# Angular event binding not working as expected

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a form which contains details such as username and email. I have a different field aside where I want the text the user types be displayed. The event binding seems not to work within my form but when I place it outside it works. I need it to work within my form. Any help is appreciated. 
Trying to do something like this 
**HTML**

```
<label for="typeahead-basic">Enter text</label>
        <input id="typeahead-basic" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="myModel"/>
        <pre>Model: {{ myModel }}</pre><br/>
**TS** <br/>
public myModel: any; <br/><br/>
Below is my code <br/><br/>

**HTML**``

  <div class="row" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12">

<!--      left-side-->
      <form class="shadow-lg p-3" [formGroup]="registrationForm" style="min-height: calc(100vh - 100px);position:relative">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light mb-2 ">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <h5 class="text-dark text-center font-weight-bold">
              Create New User
            </h5>
          </a>
          <h6>Enter the name of the user you want to create here and click the "create user once complete."</h6>
        </nav>

        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="exampleInputName" class="form-label">Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName" aria-describedby="nameHelp"
                 placeholder="Enter name of user here" [(ngModel)]="myModel"> **OVER HERE**
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Organization Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                 placeholder="username@business.org">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3 form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <!-- Change input type to be able to accept dynamic data -->
            <input [type]="fieldTextType ? 'text' : 'password'" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1"
                   placeholder="Enter strong password here" formControlName="password">

            <div class="input-group-append">
                  <span class="input-group-text">
                    <i
                      class="fa"
                      [ngClass]="{
                        'fa-eye-slash': !fieldTextType,
                        'fa-eye': fieldTextType
                      }"
                      (click)="toggleFieldTextType()"
                    ></i>
                  </span>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="mb-3 form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword2" class="form-label">Confirm Password</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <!-- Change input type to be able to accept dynamic data -->
            <input [type]="repeatFieldTextType ? 'text' : 'password'" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2"
                   placeholder="Repeat strong password here" formControlName="confirmPassword">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                  <span class="input-group-text">
                    <i
                      class="fa"
                      [ngClass]="{
                        'fa-eye-slash': !repeatFieldTextType,
                        'fa-eye': repeatFieldTextType
                      }"
                      (click)="toggleRepeatFieldTextType()"
                    ></i>
                  </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
          <label class="form-label">Role</label>
          <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
            <option selected>Select role here</option>
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="w100 align-items-center">
          <button class="btn-primary align-middle btn" style="float:none;margin:auto;display:block;border-radius:8px;">
            <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            Create User
          </button>
        </div>

      </form>



    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-sm-12" style="background-color: azure" >

<!--      right-side-->
      <div style="width: 24rem; float: none; margin: auto; display: block;">
        <div class="row card mt-4">
          <img src="assets/images/avatar.png" class="card-img-top" alt="avatar" height="150px" width="150px">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Model: {{ myModel }}</p> **OVER HERE**
            <p class="card-text">Email: </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <h5 >Preview</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <p>Enter user details on the left panel to see a profile version of the user here</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div><br/><br/>

**TS**<br/>
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-user',
  templateUrl: './create-user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-user.component.css']
})
export class CreateUserComponent implements OnInit {

  registrationForm: FormGroup;
  fieldTextType: boolean;
  repeatFieldTextType: boolean;

  public myModel: any;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initRegForm();
  }

  initRegForm() {
    this.registrationForm = this.fb.group({
      email: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: ["", Validators.required],
      confirmPassword: ["", Validators.required]
    });
  }

  toggleFieldTextType() {
    this.fieldTextType = !this.fieldTextType;
  }

  toggleRepeatFieldTextType() {
    this.repeatFieldTextType = !this.repeatFieldTextType;
  }

}
```

Comment: Try not to mix reactive forms with ngModel.
Use only reactive forms, and use something like this to show the content in the html.
`{{ this.myFormGroup.get('field1').value }}`

Comment: Next time please provide example with working application for to get better understandign and answers.
You need to connect properly your elements just see example here.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/input-ngmodel
Sometimes you do not require control in your reactive forms so You can mix things up reactive form without some input for different purpose. Then also you can bind to (ngModelChange)="changeMyText($event)" and use it as you want

Answer (score 0):

I guess it doesn't work because you need to add the **name** attribute to the *input* in order to work.
Try like this:

```
<input 
   id="typeahead-basic" 
   type="text" 
   class="form-control"  
   [(ngModel)]="myModel"
   name="myModel"
/>
```

**IMPORTANT**: *In any case, **mixing together Reactive forms and Template-Driven (ngModel) is not a good practice**.*